# How to test for a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

Say X is a data expression in Scheme. I am wondering if there is a way to test if X is a list, and if so, my machine will output `#t`, otherwise it will output `#f`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `list?`:

```
   (list? 42)
=> #f
   (list? '(1 2 3))
=> #t
```

Comment: Okay, so here is my problem: Let s be a data expression. Write a functional expression that evaluates to the boolean #t if and only if s is a non-null list whose first data expression is a non-null list (and evaluates to the boolean #f otherwise).

Comment: It sounds like a task that you're meant to work through in order to learn something :)

Comment: This is a segment of a problem I am working on yes, but I am stuck and I need some help.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Shouldn't this work? (not (null? (first (first s))))

Comment: That's a good start, but you also need to consider the case where `s` is not a non-empty list, or where the first element of `s` is not a non-empty list. You'll probably find `and` useful.

Comment: How would I use the and function again? (I'm kinda new to scheme) I tried this: (not (null? ((first s)) and (s)))

Comment: Since `and` is a function, it comes first in the list: `(and x y z)` returns `#t` if all of `x`, `y` and `z` are `#t`.

Comment: I need help with this syntax now  (list? ((first s) (and (s))))